# Cljs macros requiring fully qualified symbols

Tags: clojure, macros, clojurescript

At a normal repl this works:

```
(defmacro evaluate
  [to-eval]
  (eval to-eval))
(evaluate +) ;=> #function[clojure.core/+]
```

However in clojurescript when using separate files like so:

```
file one: macro.clj
(ns space.macro)
(defmacro evaluate
  [to-eval]
  (eval to-eval))

file two: core.cljs
(ns space.core
  (:require-macros [space.macro :refer [evaluate]))
(evaluate clojure.core/+) ;=> No error
(evaluate +) ;=> Unable to resolve symbol: + in this context
```

We get some errors. Which begs the question why? And how do you fix this?

Comment: If you choose an example without `eval` in it this question will be more informative. If this is a question about using macro's to eval stuff in ClojureScrips that's fine as well. It will just help in answering if we know between these.

Comment: It is a question about "using macro's to eval stuff in ClojureScrips".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you need to have the symbol `+` get **evaluated before it's handed to the macro** so that the symbol is resolved before it's handed to the other namespace. You can do that with quoting like so:

```
(defmacro evaluate
  [to-eval]
  `(eval ~to-eval))
```

Check out the chapter on macros in "Clojure For the Brave and True" for a better explanation: http://www.braveclojure.com/writing-macros/#Simple_Quoting

Comment: Using that I get this error: `WARNING: Use of undeclared Var cljs.core/eval at line # src/cljs/modern_cljs/core.cljs` because cljs has no eval.

Comment: I added some bold text to emphasize that you need the symbol to get evaluated (as in having it's code completely) before the macro process finishes. Clojurescript does not have an equivalent to clojure (on the JVM's) `eval`